# Twain detect landscape for scanning

Tags: image-scanner, twain

I am writing a program to get the images from a twain device. The problem is when I set the mode to landscape from the scanner gui not my program, I cannot detect it and the image is rotated wrong. If I understand the spec right ICAP_ORIENTATION should return if it is landscape or portrait or different rotation. The one scanner I try it on always returns TWOR_ROT180 whether I set landscape or portrait. With a different scanner I get TWOR_ROT90 so I think it is sending the right code to get it. Do I understand this wrong or am I doing something else wrong? Is there a different way to detect landscape? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I was getting the capability ICAP_ORIENTATION the wrong way, so it was sending me wrong information before making the changes.

Comment: A bug in TWAIN or a misunderstanding of the API?